# Android ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException class View

Tags: android, arrays, view

The error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
 at WeekView.getMoreEvents(WeekView.java:614)
```

In a class that extends View, I get a list of the id in this way:

```
public void setElencoIdOperatori(int[] id_nome_op){
this.id_nome_op = id_nome_op;
}
```

Then, with this method, I must compare **id_nome_op** with **eventRect.event.getIdOperatore().** When are the same, I want to add the event to the array **eventRects**.  Thanks for your help

```
    private void getMoreEvents(Calendar day){
// Get more events if the month is changed.
if(mEventRects ==null)
    mEventRects =newArrayList<EventRect>();

if(mMonthChangeListener ==null&&!isInEditMode())
    thrownewIllegalStateException("You must provide a MonthChangeListener");

// If a refresh was requested then reset some variables.
if(mRefreshEvents){
    mEventRects.clear();
mFetchedMonths =newint[3];
} 

  ...

    // Get events of this month.
if(mFetchedMonths[1]<1||mFetchedMonths[1]!= day.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1||mRefreshEvents){
        if(!containsValue(lastFetchedMonth,day.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)&&!isInEditMode()){
            List<WeekViewEvent> events =mMonthChangeListener.onMonthChange(day.get(Calendar.YEAR),day.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
sortEvents(events);
for(WeekViewEventevent: events){
                cacheEvent(event);
}
        }
        mFetchedMonths[1]= day.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
}
...

    // Prepare to calculate positions of each events.
ArrayList<EventRect> tempEvents =newArrayList<EventRect>(mEventRects);
mEventRects =newArrayList<EventRect>();

for(intj =1;j <=id_nome_op.length;){
        ArrayList<EventRect> eventRects =newArrayList<EventRect>();
for(EventRect eventRect : tempEvents){
            if(eventRect.event.getIdOperatore() == id_nome_op[j])
                eventRects.add(eventRect);
    }
        computePositionOfEvents(eventRects);
j++;

 }
}
```

Comment: You start your outermost `for` loop at `int j = 1`. Since arrays are zero-based, this is causing your index in `id_nome_op[j]` to be off by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard understanding your code, but I think you might have a problem here:

```
for(int j =1;j <=id_nome_op.length;) {
    ArrayList<EventRect> eventRects =newArrayList<EventRect>();
  for(EventRect eventRect : tempEvents){
        if(eventRect.event.getIdOperatore() == id_nome_op[j])
            eventRects.add(eventRect);
  }
    computePositionOfEvents(eventRects);
 j++;

}
```

When you access  `id_nome_op[j]`.
Try changing the loop to:

```
j < id_nome_op.length
```

As @Mike M pointed out, you also need initalizing your outer loop to `0`, as you want to get all the items in your array:

```
for(int j = 0; j < id_nome_op.length;)
```